# Setting the default `String` value of an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, default-value, getter

I'm relatively new to C#, so the concept of default values is somewhat confusing to me.

I currently have an object which contains two `String` values, `serialNumber` and `fullPath`. It's a simple object containing nothing but these two Strings and respective getter methods (they are not to be changed after Object creation; hence the absence of setter methods).

I want to put a List of these objects into a `CheckedListBox`. I want the box to display only the serial number and not the full path. [According to MSDN](http://marker.to/pV35DA), the `CheckedListBox` uses the default String value of the object. How can I set this to `serialNumber` when the object is created? Again, it should not be changed afterwards. Also, I'm not a big fan of the `get` and `set` keywords (I come from a Java background), so if if possible, I'd like to do this with more conventional getters/setters as I've done below for purposes of code readability.

```
class ModuleData
{

  private String serialNumber;
  private String fullPath;


  public ModuleData(String serialNumber, String fullPath)
  {
     this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
     this.fullPath = fullPath;
  }

  public String getSerialNumber()
  {
     return serialNumber;
  }

  public String getFullPath()
  {
     return fullPath;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return serialNumber;
  }

  public String DefaultValue
  {
     return serialNumber;
  }

}
```

Comment: It is ToString(), capital T

Comment: Using the conventions from a different language results in pain in the long run. Don't write Java in C#. They're two different languages.

Comment: By the way, your link to MSDN is a ambiguos. It could be considered SPAM...

Comment: @Steve Perfect, it works like a charm, much appreciated. Please make your comment an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: @audiFanatic that *shouldn't* "work like a charm" - it is missing a very important piece: `override`

Comment: It's a valid question, the documentation refers to "the default string", without explaining what that is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Like I said, I'm new to the language, so I don't expect to be perfect. For most things I prefer C# to Java, but the get and set keywords are so ambiguous to me and I really do not like them, to me a ToString method is much more readable, but that's just my own 2 cents

Comment: How are `get` and `set` *ambiguous*? (`ToString()` not being a property, We can ignore for now). The property syntax ensures we end up with clean, consistent methods.

Comment: @sasjaq Why not upvote it? There's no such thing as a stupid question. I'm new to the language and I need a place to ask questions. Is that not what this site is for after all? My Google searches were not returning good results (I probably wasn't using the correct keywords, so it's probably my fault), so I asked here to get a human answer.

Comment: @sasjaq, you've inspired me to upvote this question.  As it's useful to people learning about class creation, private setters, and polymorphism.

Comment: @sasjaq How is this not a serious question? I'm trying to learn the language (on my own, for work) and I have a serious application for my question. SO is a knowledge base and in order to be a good knowledge base, we need a combination of advanced and beginner topics. C# isn't a language taught in most universities, so having a knowledge base of questions of varying difficulty is essential to its survival. Considering that you only have 440 reputation, I don't think you're really in a position to determine what's a good question or not; you're outnumbered, give it up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`string` or `String`'s default value, [`default(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx), is `null`, but that's not what the documentation refers to. It refers to the object's `ToString()` value, [which you can override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Try something like this, using *real* C# conventions (look how readable it is!), also notice the [`override` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx):

```
public class ModuleData
{
    public ModuleData(string serialNumber, string fullPath)
    {
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        FullPath = fullPath;
    }

    public string SerialNumber { get; private set; }

    public string FullPath { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return SerialNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good catch with the override keyword. VS yelled at me when I forgot it

Answer (score 1):

To get the string representation of a class instance you override the ToString method returning your desidered value. In your code you write toString() (lowercase T) and thus being C# case sensitive it is not the correct override.

Just change to

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
     return serialNumber;
 }
```

Comment: Had to choose khellang as he included the override keyword first, hope you don't take offense to that.